# Expand relative positioned parent to height of absolute child

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I intend to have a fluid height header, with a middle content section that expands to the available height and a footer anchored to the bottom. Like so:

[image: layout]

```
<html>
<body>
<header>
     <h1>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami</h1>

     <h2>ribs tongue cow </h2>

</header>
<article>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Rage_Against_The_Machine.jpg/250px-Rage_Against_The_Machine.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<footer>
     <h3>read more</h3>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    height:100%;
}
article {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
header {
    background-color:red;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:blue;
    height:64px;
}
.content {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background-color:pink;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width : 66%;
    float:left;
}
.image {
    float:left;
    width: 34%;
    position:relative;
    right:0;
}
```

**Requirements:**

1. Content div should stretch the available height between header and
   footer
2. Content div should hide overflow of text (no scrollbars). No content
   should appear beneath footer.
3. Page should not have scrollbars
4. Footer should be positioned at the bottom of the page
5. Header has dynamic height
6. Image should accompany content on the right side.

From what I know, I cannot stretch the height of a div to the height of it's absolute child, are there any tricks that will allow me to get the desired layout?

**My problem:**
Edit: The default WebView browser on the Samsung Galaxy S3 does not support flexbox, which actually works on Chrome at the moment.

[image: requirements]

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/EcUwUbUf/6/edit

Comment: Did you try giving position relative to body?

Comment: Your question is a little bit difficult to follow. Can you isolate in words specifically what does not work for you with this code? Are you trying to match the height of the content div to the height of the image?

Comment: Btw you don't need floats or clears for this layout unless I'm gravely misunderstanding (which is possible!)

Comment: Sorry I've edited to clarify the question a little. @EvilDevil Making the body relative positioned makes the footer not anchor to the bottom of the page. It also collapses the height of the body to the height of all it's children.

Comment: @Zaqx no I am actually trying to make the `content` div expand in height so it fills up the height between the header and footer. I've updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having comes from your use of floats and position absolute. Both of which were never intended for this type of layout and are no longer best practice.

I've rewritten your demo below to use `display:inline-block` which also wasn't intended for this sort of layout but it is a better solution for this type of problem and  is current best practice.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/efEGukar/4/edit?output

The `flexbox` set of properties are specifically designed for this sort of layout and are a vastly better solution that will give you more control on how your site reacts to varying screen sizes. However, browsers are still adding support and it's not widespread just yet: [see the current list here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). This is future best practice, so if you're learning CSS take this approach.

[Here is a good explanation of how to use flexbox.](http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html)

Comment: I've updated the question to further clarify my requirements. Your version would be perfect if it could force everything to fit in the viewport without scrolling. e.g. `content` should never push `footer` from the bottom of the page, and should not show underneath `footer`. The only way I've managed so far is to give height a fixed % width, like http://jsbin.com/EcUwUbUf/3/edit. This will not allow me to use a dynamic header height though :(

Comment: Thanks to your pointer to flexbox, it now works in Chrome but not the WebView browser on a Samsung Galaxy S3, which is my main target :( http://jsbin.com/EcUwUbUf/6/edit

Comment: Hey I poked around on this a little yesterday. I'm not yet an expert in flexbox (as of today, mastery of flexbox will give you a leg up on many people in industry). Perhaps this will get you a little bit further tho: http://jsbin.com/EcUwUbUf/13/edit

Comment: Also pay attention to your code formatting. The last two demos I've seen from you have had really messy indentation. It's the programming equivalent of dressing poorly, people get a bad impression.

Comment: Thanks Zaqx. Sorry about the indentation, I usually develop with an IDE which has built in auto-indentation, jsfiddle has a TidyUp function while jsbin does not and I got slack :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are seeing the scroll bar for content area (even with overflow:hidden). I assume that's the problem. You can solve this by applying overflow:hidden to body. That should avoid the scroll bar.

Comment: Sorry I've updated the question now. My problem at the moment is expanding the `content` div to be fill the height between the header and footer. You can have a look at the jsfiddle link for the picture